# How to rebuild node modules with npm?

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs

I'm a complete beginner at Node so maybe my question is probably very naive, sorry about that.

I created my first project at work with Grunt.

Grunt uses Node, so now I have a nice folder `node_modules` at the root of my project, with several modules inside. Everything is working fine.

I added `node_modules/*` in my `.gitignore`, assuming that I would rebuild it easily from another place.

Then I go home, I retrieve my project with git and now I don't know how to rebuild the node modules.

Is there an `npm` command that would read `package.json`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try `npm i`, a short version of `npm install` inside your directory where `package.json` exists.